# extremly slow lan speed between the working station and the server

Tags: networking, domain, windows-server-2012-r2, local-area-network

when you are transfer a file to our server it takes realy long time but when you are on the server and transfer a file from a drive to another it just do it immediately i had tried a ping test and there was no packet loss i had testet the cables and there was no loose connections we are using level one fast Ethernet 32 ports switch and have cat 5e cables. will it help to change the switch to a gigabit and the cables to cat 8 s-ftp or fiber optics or are there any other solutions that i can try first. we are using domain network and our servers is virtual which we are using Hyper-v for
[task manager performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFk2x.png)
this is the lan speed test log

```
Version 1.3.2
OS Version: Windows Server 2012
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v2 @ 2.60GHz
Date: 05/10/2016
Time: 08:06:14
Program Parameters: 0
High Performance Timer: 0.0000001

 Test File: F:\Dokumenter\Ny mappe\NW_SpeedTest.dat (data server direct)
 Write Time = 41.2870400 Seconds
 Write Speed = 1,743.8886400 Mbps 218 MB/s = 1.74 Gbps = 13.1 GB/min= 784.7 GB/hr  = 18.8 TB/day 
 Read Time = 49.8332967 Seconds
 Read Speed = 1,444.8171120 Mbps = 180.6 MB/s= 10.8 GB/min = = 650.2 GB/hr = 15.6 TB/day

Test File: D:\AdData\NW_SpeedTest.dat(SQL Server Direct)
 Write Time = 9.6150333 Seconds
 Write Speed = 7,488.2736000 Mbps = 56.2 GB/min = 3.37 TB/hr = 80.9 TB/day 
 Read Time = 24.8913752 Seconds
 Read Speed = 2,892.5681840 Mbps = 361.6 MB/s  = 21.7 GB/min  = 1.3 TB/hr = 31.2 TB/day 


Version 1.3.2 
OS Version: Windows 8
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz
Date: 05/10/2016
Time: 07:43:09
Program Parameters: 0
High Performance Timer: 0.000000311

 Test File: \\SINDALSQL\App\ADDATA\NW_SpeedTest.dat (SQL server transfer)
 Write Time = 778.4404262 Seconds
 Write Speed = 92.4926240 Mbps = 693.7 MB/min = 41.6 GB/hr = 998.9 GB/day 
 Read Time = 768.4912147 Seconds
 Read Speed = 93.6900720 Mbps  =702.7 MB/min = 42.2 GB/hr = 1.01 TB/day

Test File: H:\Ny mappe\NW_SpeedTest.dat(Data Server transfer)
 Write Time = 812.1863304 Seconds
 Write Speed = 88.6496080 Mbps  664.9 MB/min = 39.9 GB/hr = 957.4 GB/day 
 Read Time = 784.4311220 Seconds
 Read Speed = 91.7862640 Mbps = 688.4 MB/min = 41.3 GB/hr = 991.3 GB/day
```

[the speed on my nas server while doing the backup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiEcv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, upgrade to a gigabit switch.

To be honest I'm surprised that you are getting the throughput that you are. Fast Ethernet is 100mbps, that's 100 million bits per second. In reality there is always other network traffic and handshaking, so I'd never expect to get the full 100mbps. So to me your figures are surprisingly good: 92.5mbps and 88.7mbps write and 93.7mbps and 91.8mbps read. So your network is running almost flat out during your file copy. So upgrade your switch to a faster one - gigabit.

A gigabit switch will give you a 10x speed gain over your current fast Ethernet. Your existing cat5e cables should be fine for that. Beyond gigabit there is 10 gigabit (10GbE). If you have the budget for 10GbE then it might be worth going for but that may require new cabling.

Comment: but isn't cat 5e so good isolated? so you are getting some interference yeah i also thougth about a 10gbe but they are realy expensive plus then i need to change the cables to get use of it  since cat5e  have only have a bandwitch on 100mhz = 1 Gbit/s. but the actual problem we have with slow speed is that when we are runnig C5  it takes forever to load but if you do it directly on the server then that happends immediately

Comment: Your switch is the limiting factor not your cables. Cat5e is good for both fast ethernet (100mbps) and gigabit (1gbps). Your existing cables are fine. The problem is that your switch is "fast ethernet" - it was "fast" once but not by modern standards. Just replace your switch with a gigabit one. If money is an issue and you need all 32 ports then get a smaller gigabit switch that you can afford, plus your server and YOUR computers into that, keep everyone else on the old fast ethernet switch and chain the two together.

Comment: can that also be the reason when we are doing a back up to altaro to our nas server then the speed is around 10-100 kbps

Comment: 10-100kbps seems very slow. Are you sure you mean kbps and not kBps or mbps? (kbps = 1000 bits per second, kBps = 1000 bytes per second, so a little "b" or big "B" is significant.) I would replace your switch, and then investigate the speed of your NAS. If the speed you are quoting is correct then I think there might be something else going on, but its easier to deal with one problem at a time.

Comment: is kBps and i am not sure if it runs through 1 or 2 switches  as is located in one of our other halls i wonder if that might could be our surveillance(since there is also some delay on it) that are eating it since it connected to the same switch as our nas or if it is a bad switch or a loose connection

Comment: just got a gigabit switch and my nas backup speed is still the same as you can see in the picture it have GBE ethernet

Comment: Omini, please accept his answer. And then consider hiring an it professional to have a look on your network. Serverfault is not suitable nor intended as a support forum. But from what I read someone should really take a look.

Comment: If you still have issues there is another part in your network that does not support gigabit or purposely limits bandwidth. But this becomes too broad to discuss here and is a close reason.

Comment: if is not a support forum then what is it so then? since alot of people are asking for help in here